# Получить JSON от API и вывести в TableView

Tags: ios, json, swift

Подскажите, как можно это реализовать.
Имеем ссылку на JSON

> urlToRequest = ="formatio.ru/api/v1/events?q=&city_id=&tag_id=&start_date=2015-01-01&end_date"

Имеем первую функцию:
Принимает URL записанный как String. Возвращает объект типа NSData(Как я понял, после выполнения там находятся просто-напросто "сырые" данные)

```
 func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest))
}
```

Далее имеем 2 функцию, которая эти "сырые" данные будет обрабатывать(парсить)
Принимает объект NSData, выдает объект типа NSDictionary(Выбираем этот тип данных так как он лучше всего подходит для хранения JSON'ов)

```
func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary{
    var error: NSError?
    var dictionaryFullJson: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

    return dictionaryFullJson
}
```

Далее, как я понимаю, 
1)мы должны записать наш dictionaryFullJson в переменную типа NSDictionary в уже в функциию viewDidLoad() (Это ведь главная функция?)

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let storeJSONFromApi = parseJSON(getJSON(urlToRequest: String))
}
```

Все, после запуска приложения имеем наш Json, помещенный в NSDictioanary в константе storeJSONFromApi.

Верно ли я все понимаю?

Далее нужно вывести сам JSON из Dictionary в TableView. Как это можно реализовать?

Или же все-таки "Код, написанный в глобальной области используется в качестве точки входа для программы" и надо писать просто за границами других функций нашу

```
let storeJSONFromApi = parseJSON(getJSON(urlToRequest: String))
```

и она выполнится, так как будет являться точкой входа в программу?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вынесите этот функционал в отдельный класс, вот например:

```
// для удобства создаем typealias, это тот же словарь, но так будет удобнее
typealias JSONObject = [String: AnyObject]

// реализуем синглтон, для доступа к этому классу из любой части программы
class APIController { 
    class var sharedController: APIController {
        struct Singleton {
            static let sharedIntance = APIController()
        }
        return Singleton.sharedIntance
    }
}


// собственно, сами запросы
    extension APIController {
        private struct Consts {
            static let baseURL = "https://formatio.ru/api/v1"
            static let parsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.MyApp.queues.parsing", nil)
        }
        func runAPICall(call: String, params: [String: String], completion: (JSONObject?, NSError?) -> Void) {
            var paramsString = ""
            for (key, value) in params {
                if let paramValue = value.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    if count(paramsString) > 0 { paramsString+="&" }
                    paramsString+="\(key)=\(paramValue)"
                }
            }
            if let url = NSURL(string: call+"?"+paramsString) {
                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url), queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { response, data, error in
                    if let err = error {
                        completion(nil, err)
                    } else {
                        dispatch_async(Consts.parsingQueue) { () -> Void in
                            var parseError: NSErrorPointer = nil
                            let object = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: parseError) as? JSONObject
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                                completion(object, nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

вот пример использования:

```
class SomeViewController: UITableViewController {

// переменная для хранения полученных объектов
var items: [JSONObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
    // Шлем запрос:
    APIController.sharedController.runAPICall("events", ["term": "Can't Stop", "attribute": "songTerm", "entity": "album"], completion: { response, error in
    // тут обрабатываем ответ или ошибку позднее, после его завершения и завершения парсинга
        switch (error, response?["results"] as? [JSONObject]) {
        case (.Some(let err), _): // обрабатываем ошибку
        case (_, .Some(let objects)): // здесь я ожидаю массив, поэтому в switch проверяю, что это массив словарей с помощью 'as? [JSONObject]'
        self.items = objects
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
        default: // нет ошибки или не те данные, обрабатываем
        }
    })
}

}
```